# JS: Use different input data for a function and check if no variable is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

*I think I ran into a wrong direction and now I'm really stucked. That's why I'm asking for your help.*

**Summary: I'm trying to switch between two possible input data of a function and I need to check for empty value, to get a valid result array. The array structure is fixed (I can't change that) and if any value is missing or the input object doesn't match (for example less elements then expected), the result should be `data = false`**

There is a function with one parameter (`template`). But the input differs:

**First** of all,

1. I have to check if the data comes as an simple object into the function

like

```
template = { type: 'anything', 0: 'Book title', 1: 'Article title', 2: 'Name', 3: '1' }
```

or

2. if there is a `ReactiveDict`-variable (which I would access like this: `template.dict.get('type')`) from where the data has to be taken.

In the latter case the data is also stored in the variable `template`, but I have to change the access to it slightly: `template.dict.get('type')` vs. `template.type`

3. It could also be the case, that there is no (correct) data at all: For example no data or an object with less or more elements as expected.

So I tried to use this, to switch between both input types:

```
const   type    = template.type || template.dict.get('type')
```

This doesn't work as sometimes I get the error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. I think if there is no input type at all, so `template.type` is undefined and there is no `ReactiveDict`, which means `template.dict` is undefined.

**Second** I need to check if all variables has values: Each (trimmed) value needs to be a string.

For future development I would like to verify the data of each variable (I think with regEx) to make this function a bit better. Example: edition should be a number (but stored as a string).

---

**function**

```
function(template) {
    const   type    = template.type || template.dict.get('type'),   // How to do this better?
            docId   = '12345';
    let     data    = false;

    if (type === 'anything') { 
        const   title       = template[0] || template.dic.get(0).value, // How to do those better?
                article     = template[1] || template.dic.get(1).value,
                author      = template[2] || template.dic.get(2).value,
                edition     = template[3] || template.dic.get(3).value;

        if (title && article && author && edition)      // How to check each value smarter?
            data = [
                [
                    { title: title.trim() },
                    { article: article.trim() },
                    { author: author.trim() },
                    { reference: docId }
                ],
                {
                    title: title.trim(),
                    type : type
                },
                {
                    article: article.trim()
                },
                {
                    author     : author.trim(),
                    edition    : edition.trim()
                },
                {
                    reference: docId
                }
            ];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning,
replace

```
const type    = template.type || template.dict.get('type')
```

by

```
const type = template.type || (template.dict && template.dict.get('type'))
```

I see you use es6 so you can do destructuring affectation:
const [title,author,article,author] = template
but after it don't solve the fact you have to check they are undefined or not, you can use an object instead

```
o = {}
var oneValueIsEmpty = false
["title","article","author","edtiton"].forEach(function(key,i){
    o[key] = template[i] || template.dic.get(i).value
    oneValueIsEmpty = oneValueIsEmpty || !o[key]
})

 if (!oneValueIsEmpty )     
            data = [
                [
                    { title: o.title.trim() },
                    { article: o.article.trim() },
                    { author: o.author.trim() },
                    { reference: docId }
                ],
                {
                    title: o.title.trim(),
                    type : type
                },
                {
                    article: o.article.trim()
                },
                {
                    author     : o.author.trim(),
                    edition    : o.edition.trim()
                },
                {
                    reference: docId
                }
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
const type = template.type || template.dict.get('type')
```

change into

```
const type = template && template.dict
  ? template.dict.get('type')
  : template.type;
```

and

```
const title = template && template.dict
  ? template.dict.get(0).value
  : template[0];
```

**Edit:**
Also I would recommend explicitly writing const and let before each variable and not using comma to declare multiple variables. It always is a mess for next guy who has to maintain your code although this is very opinionated.

Comment: Do I need `template && template.dict` instead of just `template.dict`? As `template` is the parameter of the function...?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring:

```
const   type    = template.type || template.dict.get('type'),
```

But here you're referring to template.dic.get as opposed to dict, that won't help much.

```
if (type === 'anything') { 
    const   title       = template[0] || template.dic.get(0).value, // How to do those better?
            article     = template[1] || template.dic.get(1).value,
            author      = template[2] || template.dic.get(2).value,
            edition     = template[3] || template.dic.get(3).value;
```

you can use:

```
if (typeof template.dict !== 'undefined')
```

To check whether the object exists.